# Rails 3.1 - rendering an individual mime-type to a http-request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mime-types

I would like to use server-sent events in an Rails 3.1-project. Server-sent events have to include messages of the mime-type "text/event-stream". So is it possible to take a String for example like:

```
@message = 'data: {"title": "this is a title"}\n\n'
```

and render it to a HTTP like that:

```
EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(URL).post({
  :message => render :text/event-stream => @message 
})
```

Would be nice to know if this works or how I should handle it otherwise.

Comment: @james_schorr I updated the question. After thinking and sleeping over it a night I thought that it might be that rendering though is the right way to solve what I want to do.

Comment: That looks to me like it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use a standard action to render your response like so...

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
render :text => "data:#{Random.rand(0..10000)}\n\n", :content_type => "text/event-stream"
```

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't respond to your answer, but I had given up on the project...